# how to pass a variable length list of models to a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a website where products with a variable number of variations can be added to a database.

I use a form where the product can be filled in, and then variations can be added. those variations are based on another model. But when passing those variations to the method it's not in a list. How can i make them be passed as a list?

```cs
<form id="partialform" asp-action="AddNewProduct" asp-route-Category="Skate" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:inline-block;width:100%;" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#AppendProductHere" data-ajax-mode="replace">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="appendpartformhere">
        <partial name="AddProductBase" model="new Product()" />

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <partial name="AddCategoryAllBase" model="new CategoryAll()" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Skate.Use" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Skate.Use" class="form-control" id="SkateUse" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Skate.Use" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            //more labels and inputs
        </div>
    </div>
    <partial name="AddVariationSkate" model="new VariationSkate()" />
    <div id="addpartialSkate"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Finish" class="btn btn-default" id="FinishAddingVariations" />
    </div>
</form>
```

partial to be inserted into above on clicking button

```
<div class="allSkates">
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

                <partial name="AddProductItemBase" model="new ProductItems()" />
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="EANCode" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="EANCode" class="form-control VariationsOnProduct">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Size" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Size" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Size" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" name="name" value="Skate" class="addItem">add variation</button>
                </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

method i'm trying to call

```
public ActionResult AddNewProduct(ListSkates skatelist, string Category, Product NewProduct, CategoryAll NewAll)
```

class which i'm trying to fill with skatelist, but productitem and variationskates remain null, Skate does get filled

```
public class ListSkates
{
    public CategorySkate Skate { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductItems> productitem { get; set; }
    public IList<VariationSkate> VariationSkates { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, your inputs need to be named like: `VariationSkates[N].EANCode`, when `N` is an index. You can do this manually in various ways, but it's an enormous pain and prone to error. Your best bet is to use a client-side library that supports two-way model binding like Angular or Vue.

In general, you'll create a client-side template of the HTML that should be displayed for each `VariationSkate` instance (i.e. your form fields) and then you'll bind the list of `VariationSkates` (as a JavaScript object) to a repeating block that uses this template. The client-side library, then, will manage the indexing and insertion/removal of HTML.

The exact methodology varies depending on the client-side library you use, and in general, an in-depth guide is far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow here. You'll need to do your own research, pick a library, and consult that library's documentation, as well as other online resources. Once you've attempted a solution, if you run into issues, you can ask a more specific question about that.

Comment: Would i have to rewrite the whole project, or can I just use it for one piece? And can this be done without angular/vue/..., or is this the only possible way?Thank you already.